# Creating a link to a web project page from another web project page in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net

How do you set a link on a project web page in .Net using c# to point to another project webpage in the same visual studio solution?

Comment: Just link every other link in the internet. You give it a `href` that points to whatever URL you are able to access the target web page with